# "A token may not be passed in as a PaymentMethod. Instead, use payment_method_data with type=card Stripe Error in Laravel

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

My Stripe Controller :-

```
 try {
        $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
        $customer = $stripe->customers->create([
            // 'email' => 'email@example.com',
            'email' => $user->email,
            'name' => $user->name
            // 'name' => 'test'
        ]);
        $payemntid = $stripe->paymentIntents->create([
            'amount' => 100 * $total_amount,
            'currency' => 'usd',
            'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
            'customer' => $customer->id,
            'payment_method' => $request->stripeToken
        ]);
```

The Error Comes :- {"success":false,"message":"A token may not be passed in as a PaymentMethod. Instead, use payment_method_data with type=card and card[token]=tok_1KtVZxSF6gyJgm24q5ZpEFWD."}

Any Idea How to Fix This.
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 4):

As the error states it's not allowed to pass the token into the `payment_method`. You have to use `payment_method_data`.

---

Your code should look something like this:

```
try {
        $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
        $customer = $stripe->customers->create([
            // 'email' => 'email@example.com',
            'email' => $user->email,
            'name' => $user->name
            // 'name' => 'test'
        ]);
        $payemntid = $stripe->paymentIntents->create([
            'amount' => 100 * $total_amount,
            'currency' => 'usd',
            'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
            'customer' => $customer->id,
            'payment_method_data' => [
                'type' => 'card',
                'card' => [
                    'token' => $request->stripeToken
                ]
            ]
        ]);
```

Comment: Sir BY Using This New Error Comes :- {"success":false,"message":"Missing required param: payment_method_data[type]."} What can i do now ?

Comment: On stripe dashboard it shows The customer has not completed the payment. and the payment is incomplete any idea about this

Comment: I updated my answer, i forgot to specify type aswell.

Comment: No Issue Thank You For Your Help Could you please tell me about why this payments are incomple

Comment: Well I don't really deal with Stripe, and I can't find anything useful in docs.
But my guess is, since the `payment_method` you previously supplied wasn't correct, the payment was created but there was no data regarding what type of payment it was, therefore getting an `incomplete` status. But once again, I am not sure if this is correct or not.

Comment: Found this:
" Stripe categorizes a transaction as "incomplete" when a "payment intent" was created, but your user never completed the payment. In other words, an incomplete transaction means the user went to the payment page, but never took action. When it comes to an incomplete transaction, the sale was simply not made.
"

Comment: Okay Thank You for this i'll look more into it if i get any solution will update here

Comment: I assume you're testing local and not actually finishing an order, so the payments being incomplete make sense. You don't necessarily have to update here since I have no use for anything Stripe related. You could however mark the answer as correct.